# angular how to order item by date from format like "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date

I'm getting a json object with number of items

```
   "[{"StartDate":"2015-01-16T00:00:00","EndDate":"2015-01-20T00:00:00"},
    {"StartDate":"2015-01-15T00:00:00","EndDate":"2015-01-16T00:00:00"}]"
```

and i want to order this on the client side table with DESC order

this is the function that request and return the json answer

```
  function getTrips() {

        //set loading indicator
        vm.searchData.isLoading = true;
        return datacontext.getTrips(vm.searchData.getTripsFilter)
            .success(function (result) {
                try {
                    //set loading indicator
                    vm.searchData.isLoading = false;
                    tripData.trips = result;
                    if (!tripData.trips) {
                        logWarning('dont find trips:(');
                        return;
                    }

                    //post-process trips for display
                    angular.forEach(tripData.trips, tripData.processTrip);

                    //start filtering trips pager
                    vm.searchData.filterTrips();
                    log('found' + tripData.trips.length + ' to this search.');

                    return tripData.trips;
                } catch (e) {
                    logError('error searching trips!', e);
                }
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                logError('error searching trips!', data);
                vm.searchData.isLoading = false;
            });
    }
```

I think mybe to add global parameter that control the order by (but I get a string) or there is a auto order by date function on angular that i don't no about:|

thank in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way your date values are formatted, either sorting them alphabetically as strings, or by first converting them to `Date` objects, will both result in correct ordering.

So, you can use the built in `orderBy` filter to sort your data. This can either be done in your controller:

```
tripData.trips = $filter('orderBy')(tripData.trips, 'StartDate', true);
```

or in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="trip in trips | orderBy:'StartDate':true">...</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: wow i didnt know i can sort by alphabetically, this is amazing thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just asking for simple sorting then here is it

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="DatesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="d in dates | orderBy:identity:true" ng-bind="d | date:'medium'"></div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('DatesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.identity = angular.identity;
    $scope.dates = [ new Date("2015-01-16T00:00:00"), new Date("2015-01-15T00:00:00"), new Date("2015-01-17T00:00:00") ];

 }]);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7zNHx/2/)

Comment: what is the date:medium ?

Comment: @shaharnakash its for format 
see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
It can be 'medium' , 'short' ,'fullDate'